# collection.AddTransient<IB>(_ => new B(x)) where arg is the return of another injected class A.GetX()?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following interfaces and classes (.Net core 3.1 console application).

```
public interface IA { string GetX(); }
public class A 
{ 
    public GetX() { return "Test"; } 
}

public interface IB { void DoSomething(); }
public class B 
{
    public B(string x) { /*...*/ } // need to call A.GetX() for x
    public void DoSomething() { /*....*/ }
}
```

And in following console application, it shows that `collection.AddTransient<IB>(_ => new B(x))` need the value `x` returned by `A.GetX()`. However, collection was already built for `A` before setting up `B`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    collection.AddTransient<IA, A>();
    var serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider(); // Had to build now to call a.GetX() for B

    var a = serviceProvider.GetService<IA>();
    var x = a.GetX();
    if (!Validated(x))
    {
        // log the error, etc.
        return; // exit
    }

    collection.AddTransient<IB>(_ => new B(x)); 
    // However, serviceProvider was already built? 
    var b = serviceProvider.GetService<IB>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building the service provider earlier is ***not*** the correct solution.

The problem is that you are ignoring, even going so far as to name it with the conventional `_`, the argument provided to your factory delegate.

This argument is the service provider.

Here is how it is used.

```
var collection = new ServiceCollection();

collection.AddTransient<IA, A>();

collection.AddTransient<IB>(provider => {
    var a = provider.GetService<IA>();
    var x = a.GetX();
    return new B(x);
}); 

var serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

var b = serviceProvider.GetService<IB>();
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I also have some code to validate `x`. And it will exit if `x` is not validated. Should the validating code in the lamba too? How to gracefully exit if it's not validated?

Comment: @ca9163d9 that sounds like an anti pattern and should be validated from the outside

Comment: Whether that is a good pattern or not is independent of where the code should go if you decide to do so. It has to go inside the factory because it requires `IA`. If `x` is invalid you must throw an appropriate exception.